# QGIS select points within certain radius

Tags: qgis, buffer, query

I've seen other threads ask very similar questions, but I haven't seen one that answers this specifically:

So, I have 4 Total sets of points.  1 set is a set of addresses in Arkansas, the other 3 are different types of toxic waste contamination sites.  What I am trying to find out is how to run a query to find and select which addresses are within 20 kilometers of any of those 3 contamination sites.

Does anyone know how I could go about doing that?

Answer (score 2):

One possibility is to do a polygon buffer around each toxic site point:

> Main Toolbar > Vector > Geoprocessing Tools > Buffer(s)

This will provide radial areas of interest around the sites, geometries which can then be used too...

...find any address points contained therein:

> Main Toolbar > Vector > Research Tools > Select By Location

All of this would likely need you to have two separate point vector layers; *toxic sites* and *addresses of concern*.